# Remove wp_get_attachment_image Image Size

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Is there any way to remove the image size of the wp_get_attachment function?

I was trying the following code with no luck, trying to get it either 100% or nothing at all.

```
echo wp_get_attachment_image($variable, array(100 . '&#37;', 100 . '&#37;'));
```

*EDIT*

This is what I ended up with that works perfectly thanks to drew010.

```
echo '<img src="'.wp_get_attachment_url($variable).'" alt="'.get_the_title().'" />';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Jrod has the correct answer IMO, but you can also just call

```
wp_get_attachment_url($variable);
```

which gives you the URL to the full image.  Then you can simply construct your own HTML markup for displaying the image.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the full size image you should use the following:

`echo wp_get_attachment_image($variable, 'full');`

Comment: It needs to be 100% or none at all.

Comment: Then you should use @drew010 solution to construct an image tag with the width and height attributes set to 100%.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use it this way: `alt="'.get_the_title().'"`

You must use `esc_attr($attachment->post_title)` or `the_title_attribute()`.

If the title has some html tags your alt attribute can crash your html outline. Trust me, a year ago I searched for over 1 hour this bug in some theme.